# Connect one SATA hard drive to two devices

Tags: hard-disk, sata, dvr

I have a DVR writing video surveillance data to SATA hard drive. I want to be able to readonly that hard drive with another computer connected to it simultaneously.

Is there a piece of hardware that would allow that? For example, a man-in-the-middle SATA controller looking transparent to the DVR but also allowing to connect another computer readonly?

Comment: I don't think it's possible... Can you attach a NAS to the DVR?

Comment: @GerardoGrignoli The DVR uses SATA to connect hard drive. Are there NASes that allow SATA and network access at the same time?